# Consumer Driven Contracts with Junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

How to properly annotate BaseTests for CDC with spring-cloud-contract?

I'm using currently

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {WithoutDbConfig.class, SomeController.class})
public abstract class BaseControllerTest {
```

as it is specified in https://spring.io/guides/gs/contract-rest/

Anybody runs it with Junit5?

Comment: I haven’t tried your specific case but in general you can just remove the RunWith annotation since Jupiter support is build into Spring testing directly (since version 5 or so).